# Solving MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to solve the following query with these data:
Some assumptions will need to be made. Please list any such assumptions
Users:

```
+---------+---------+--------+-----+--------+
| USER_ID |  EMAIL  | GENDER | AGE |  NAME  |
+---------+---------+--------+-----+--------+
| 1       | a@a.com | m      | 30  | rob    |
| 2       | a@a.com | m      | 31  | robert |
| 3       | b@b.com | f      | 18  | lucie  |
| 4       | b@b.com | f      | 22  | lulu   |
| 5       | c@c.com | m      | 10  | kim    |
| 6       | c@c.com | f      | 18  | kim    |
| 7       | c@c.com | f      | 08  | kim    |
| 8       | d@d.com | f      | 18  | JJ     |
| 9       | d@d.com | m      | 22  | Jay    |
| 10      | e@e.com | f      | 88  | Bill   |
| 11      | e@e.com | f      | 88  | Will   |
| 12      | e@e.com | f      | 60  | Will   |
| 13      | f@f.com | m      | 70  | George |
+---------+---------+--------+-----+--------+
```

Subscriptions:

```
+-----------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| SUBSCRIPTION_ID | USER_ID | SUBSCIPTION_TYPE | ACTIVE_INDICATOR |
+-----------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 1               | 2       | Magazine         | Yes              |
| 2               | 3       | Music            | CD               |
| 3               | 3       | Magazine         | Yes              |
| 4               | 3       | Video            | Yes              |
| 5               | 8       | Magazine         | Yes              |
| 6               | 9       | Video            | Yes              |
| 7               | 10      | Magazine         | No               |
| 8               | 13      | Magazine         | yes              |
+-----------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

Transactions:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| SUBSCRIPTION_ID |    ACTION    |  TIMESTAMP  |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1               | Renewal      | 2002-sep-10 |
| 2               | Renewal      | 2002-Jan-01 |
| 2               | Cancellation | 2002-Feb-01 |
| 3               | Renewal      | 2002-Aug-20 |
| 4               | Renewal      | 2002-Aug-01 |
| 4               | Renewal      | 2002-Sep-01 |
| 5               | Renewal      | 2002-Aug-01 |
| 6               | Renewal      | 2001-Sep-01 |
| 7               | Renewal      | 2002-Sep-01 |
| 7               | Cancellation | 2002-Sep-10 |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Assumptions:

1. generate a list of unique email addresses with the latest name, gender and age for a user with that email.
2. The selection criteria limit the list to users which never subscribed to anything; or; users with inactive subscriptions; or; users with active subscriptions that renewed between Sep 1st and Sep 30th of any year.

The answer should be:

```
+---------+--------+-----+--------+
|  EMAIL  | GENDER | AGE |  NAME  |
+---------+--------+-----+--------+
| a@a.com | m      | 31  | robert |
| b@b.com | f      | 22  | lulu   |
| c@c.com | f      | 08  | kim    |
| d@d.com | m      | 22  | Jay    |
| e@e.com | f      | 60  | Will   |
+---------+--------+-----+--------+
```

I am trying this query:

```
select u.user_id, email, gender, age, name
from users u 
    left join subscriptions s on u.user_id = s.user_id
where s.user_id is null
    or s.active_indicator='No'
    or u.user_id in 
    (
        select u.user_id
        from subscriptions s,transactions t, users u 
        where u.user_id = s.user_id
            and s.subscription_id = t.subscription_id
            and t.`action`='Renewal' 
            and s.active_indicator='Yes'
            and month(timestamp) = 9 
    )
```

which shows the following output:

```
+--------+---------+--------+-----+------+
| USERID |  EMAIL  | GENDER | AGE | NAME |
+--------+---------+--------+-----+------+
| 1      | a@a.com | m      | 30  | rob  |
| 4      | b@b.com | f      | 22  | lulu |
| 5      | c@c.com | m      | 10  | kim  |
| 6      | c@c.com | f      | 18  | kim  |
| 7      | c@c.com | f      | 8   | kim  |
| 11     | e@e.com | f      | 88  | will |
| 12     | e@e.com | f      | 60  | will |
+--------+---------+--------+-----+------+
```

Any ideas? I am a bit lost, the main problem I am having is that I cannot sort the list before the group by.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by

Comment: @ceejayoz how is that question supposed to help?

Comment: If this is your own database, you should redesign. It's not normalized at all

Comment: @honeybadger sorry, I must solve this with the current design, I can't redesign the db.

Comment: What normalization is missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
      ( SELECT  u.email, u.gender, u.age, u.name, 'never subscribed to anything' AS 'State'
            FROM  Users AS u
            LEFT JOIN  Subscriptions AS s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE  s.subscription_id IS NULL 
      )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
      ( SELECT  u.email, u.gender, u.age, u.name, 'inactive subscription' AS 'State'
            FROM  Users AS u
            JOIN  Subscriptions AS s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE  s.active_indicator != 'Yes' 
      )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
      ( SELECT  u.email, u.gender, u.age, u.name, 'active
              and  Sep. renewal'
            FROM  Users AS u
            JOIN  Subscriptions AS s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
            JOIN  Transactions AS t ON t.subscription_id = s.subscription_id
            WHERE  s.active_indicator = 'Yes'
              AND  MID(t.timestamp, 5, 2) = '09' 
      )
    ORDER BY  email;
```

Notice how closely this parallels your specifications.  ('or' becomes `UNION DISTINCT`.)

This formulation requires `TIMESTAMP` to be a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, not `VARCHAR`.  If you want the current output (yyyy-MMM-dd), use `DATE_FORMAT` when displaying.

Comment: (It is possible to leave the dates in the format given; but is is messier.)

Comment: Replacing `s.active_indicator = 'No'` with `s.active_indicator != 'Yes'` seems wrong, as the column has other values aside from 'Yes' and 'No' according to the data sample.

Comment: On a different note, your State column prevents the subselects from sharing any rows in the output and so using UNION DISTINCT doesn't seem justified. The only reason there might be duplicates is because they could be generated by the inner joins. But suppressing these duplicates with UNION DISTINCT doesn't seem to be a good idea. It would probably be better to prevent them using semi-joins (EXISTS or IN) instead of inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself:

I assume that max user_id for each email is the last entry for a customer.
So, I will create a view which contains the max user_id for a customer.

```
create view maxuser as
select max(user_id) as id
from users
group by email

select * from maxuser

id
2
4
7
9
12
13
```

Will create another view to get the columns for the users

```
create view userslist as
select `users`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`users`.`email` AS `email`,`users`.`gender` AS `gender`,`users`.`age` AS `age`,`users`.`name` AS `name` from (`users` join `maxuser`) where (`users`.`user_id` = `maxuser`.`id`)

select * from userslist

2    a@a.com    m    31    robert
4    b@b.com    f    22    lulu
7    c@c.com    f    8    kim
9    d@d.com    m    22    jay
12    e@e.com    f    60    will
13    f@f.com    m    70    george
```

1 - I have the list with unique email address for the lastest users

Now I am going to filter users who never subscribed to anything.

```
select u.user_id, email, gender, age, name
from userslist u left join subscriptions s
on u.user_id = s.user_id
where s.user_id is null

4    b@b.com    f    22    lulu
7    c@c.com    f    8    kim
12    e@e.com    f    60    will
```

Adding users with inactive subscriptions the query will be:

```
select u.user_id, email, gender, age, name
from userslist u left join subscriptions s
on u.user_id = s.user_id
where s.user_id is null
or s.active_indicator='no'

4    b@b.com    f    22    lulu
7    c@c.com    f    8    kim
12    e@e.com    f    60    will
```

No new rows where added to the answer. Now we are going to analyze separated the last filter.

```
create view renewedsept as
select u.user_id
from subscriptions s,transactions t, userslist u
where u.user_id = s.user_id
and s.subscription_id = t.subscription_id
-- Only renewals
and t.`action`='renewal'
 -- with active subscription
and s.active_indicator='yes'
-- renewed in september of any year
and month(timestamp) = 9
```

The final query is:

```
select u.user_id, email, gender, age, name
from userslist u left join subscriptions s
on u.user_id = s.user_id
where s.user_id is null
or s.active_indicator='no'
or u.user_id in (select user_id from renewedsept)

which give us the expected answer:

2    a@a.com    m    31    robert
4    b@b.com    f    22    lulu
7    c@c.com    f    8    kim
9    d@d.com    m    22    jay
12    e@e.com    f    60    will
```

Comment: ***"I assume that max user_id for each email is the last entry for a customer."*** That should be in the question, not in an answer. How are others supposed to know this assumption?